# why CLIENT_EVENTS are not working RTM is undefined in my slack bot?

Tags: node.js, express, slack, slack-api

i am just started to develop service for slack and i just creating a connection to the slack bot but i have facing a problem that

> Cannot read property 'RTM' of undefined

this is my code

```
const { RTMClient, CLIENT_EVENTS, RTM_EVENTS, RTM_MESSAGE_SUBTYPES } = require('@slack/client');

function handleOnAuthenticated(rtmStartData) {
    console.log(`logged in as ${rtmStartData.self.name} of team ${rtmStartData.self.team.name} but not et connected to channel`);
}

function addAuthenticatedHandler(rtm, handler) {
    rtm.on(CLIENT_EVENTS.RTM.AUTHENTICATED, handler);
}

module.exports.init = function slackClient(bot_token, logLevel) {
    rtm = new RTMClient(bot_token);
    addAuthenticatedHandler(rtm, handleOnAuthenticated);
    return rtm;
}

module.exports.addAuthenticatedHandler = addAuthenticatedHandler;
```

i dont know what is the exact problem is can anyone tell me that why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The RTM_EVENTS dictionary isn't necessary, you just need to directly subscribe to the event name as a string.

Convert:

```
function addAuthenticatedHandler(rtm, handler) {
rtm.on(CLIENT_EVENTS.RTM.AUTHENTICATED, handler);
}
```

> As Constants is V3.x ,which have been removed from V4.x

To:

```
function addAuthenticatedHandler(rtm, handler) {
rtm.on('authenticated', handler);
}
```

> Using simple strings for event names is V4.x

[migration guide](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/blob/master/migration_guide_v4.md)

Comment: Thank you this was life saver!